# Google Consent Manager Platform (CMP) is not showing everytime in debug mode

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, cmp, gdprconsentform

Sharing following code, how am I calling for CMP dialog.

```
fun initDebugConsent(deviceId: String, onConsentResponse: OnConsentResponse) {
    this.onConsentResponse = onConsentResponse

    val debugSettings = ConsentDebugSettings.Builder(activity)
        .setDebugGeography(ConsentDebugSettings.DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA)
        .addTestDeviceHashedId(deviceId)
        .build()

    val params = ConsentRequestParameters.Builder().setConsentDebugSettings(debugSettings).build()
    requestConsentInfo(params)
}

private fun requestConsentInfo(params: ConsentRequestParameters) {
    consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(activity, params, {
        if (consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable && consentInformation.consentStatus == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
            Log.d("ConsentManager", "initDebugConsent: Available & Required")
            loadForm()
        } else {
            Log.d("ConsentManager", "initDebugConsent: Neither Available or Required")
            onConsentResponse?.onResponse()
        }
    }, { error ->
        Log.e("ConsentManager", "initDebugConsent: $error")
        onConsentResponse?.onResponse(error.message)
    })
}
```

Note: It do show first time, but after consent I have to wait a lot for again testing.

Answer (score 0):

I got by resetting `consentInformation` object only in `debug` mode, as it is recommended by google team.

> Caution: This method is intended to be used for testing purposes only. You shouldn't call reset() in production code.

```
consentInformation.reset()
```